# Isn't stereo speaker a software thing?

Tags: samsung, hardware

I've got a Note 8, and heard the Galaxy S9 was coming with stereo speakers. My doubt is: can't the phone software activate the "phonecall" speaker just to have both speakers running at once? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You can hypothetically use your speaker for phonecalls to play media however the phonecall speaker is usually of low quality and low volume, you probably wouldn't even hear it make a difference...   As far as I know they've just added another speaker phone speaker, Most devices support recording the system audio in stereo with a screen recorder